# how to filter lines from timeseries dataframe by multi columns conditions

Tags: python, time-series, apply, pandas-groupby

I get this timeseries dataframe and I would like to keep row which has minmum code value at corresponding timestamp.

The dataframe is not finacial data, and i don't need groupby. I think .apply() might help to get minumum data at one timestamp. But i don't know how to write code. Can any one tell me how to do that? Thanks a lot in advance.

for example i would like to keep these rows:

```
2018-12-31 09:41:37     22182   T20     30101   error_converter_error_inu_flag  Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22188   T45     30000   error_global_converter  Converter
2018-12-31 11:33:32     22196   T06     30000   error_global_converter  Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22201   T45     30000   error_global_converter  Converter
```

from belowing rows, because they have the minum value 30000 compared to other rows at the same timestamp

```
    alarm_id    unit    code    desc    group_n
time                    
2018-12-31 09:41:37     22182   T20     30101   error_converter_error_inu_flag  Converter
2018-12-31 09:41:37     22183   T20     30102   error_converter_error_inu_voltage   Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22192   T45     30400   error_converter_status  Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22190   T45     30101   error_converter_error_inu_flag  Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22193   T45     30401   error_converter_rdyon   Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22188   T45     30000   error_global_converter  Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22194   T45     30405   error_converter_tripped     Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22191   T45     30102   error_converter_error_inu_voltage   Converter
2018-12-31 11:08:57     22189   T45     30100   error_converter_error_inu   Converter
2018-12-31 11:33:32     22199   T06     30105   error_converter_error_inu_other     Converter
2018-12-31 11:33:32     22197   T06     30100   error_converter_error_inu   Converter
2018-12-31 11:33:32     22198   T06     30101   error_converter_error_inu_flag  Converter
2018-12-31 11:33:32     22196   T06     30000   error_global_converter  Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22201   T45     30000   error_global_converter  Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22207   T45     30405   error_converter_tripped     Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22206   T45     30401   error_converter_rdyon   Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22204   T45     30102   error_converter_error_inu_voltage   Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22203   T45     30101   error_converter_error_inu_flag  Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22205   T45     30400   error_converter_status  Converter
2018-12-31 13:09:28     22202   T45     30100   error_converter_error_inu   Converter
```

Answer (score 0):

When you will give dataframe reproducible example, it will be easier, but in general `df.groupby('time').code.min()` does something you require. In case time is set as index, `df.groupby(df.index).code.min()` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much. This method can't keep other columsn. Then I borrow your suggestion and make a function and archive a result. This method works but it is not nice and compact.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'time':[8,8,8,6,6,6,3,3,3],
    'code':[30,31,32,62,61,63,56,57,55],
    'unit':['T1','T1','T1','T2','T2','T2','T3','T3','T3'],
})
print(df)
print()

def lowfilter(df,c1='time',c2='code'):
    ser=df.groupby(df[c1])[c2].min()
    ser = ser.reset_index()
    df_tmp=pd.DataFrame()
    for idx in ser.index:
        df_tmp = pd.concat([df_tmp,df[(df[c1]==ser.iloc[idx][c1]) & (df[c2]==ser.iloc[idx][c2])]])
    return df_tmp

print(lowfilter(df))
```

result:

```
   time  code unit
0     8    30   T1
1     8    31   T1
2     8    32   T1
3     6    62   T2
4     6    61   T2
5     6    63   T2
6     3    56   T3
7     3    57   T3
8     3    55   T3

   time  code unit
8     3    55   T3
4     6    61   T2
0     8    30   T1
```

The previous code is very slow, an optimization is done:

```
def lowfilter(df,c1='time',c2='code'):
    ser=df.groupby(df[c1])[c2].min()
    ser = ser.reset_index()
    return pd.merge(df,ser)
```

it output the same result but 1000 times faster